# Javascript Loop Button always takes last value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that crawls infos from tmdb. i want to work with that response. i do for example search for a movie and want to put the results(titles and the poster-images) into a table with a button.
That works fine.
For that i have a loop that creates a table with entries every loop. In 1 entry i have a button, that is supposed to call another function and give it the value(form the poster-path the movie has) that is set in the specific loop.
 Works partially...
Problem is: the value given to the new fuction is always the last value (value of the last loop).
 I dont know how to fix that :/

I already tried an  "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression"(found in this forum) which looks like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    (function(index) {

        console.log('iterator: ' + index);

    })(i);

}
```

---

Same Problems still :/

thats my script ("bbcode" and "imglink" were set before this)

```
if (this.status === 200) {

var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
totalresults = jsonResponse.total_results;

  if (totalresults === 0){ noresult(); }
  if (totalresults === 1){ oneresult(); }

  else {

    var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
    x.setAttribute("border", "1");
    document.getElementById("log").appendChild(x);


    for (var j = 0; j < totaresults; j++) {

    (function(i) {

    posterpath = jsonResponse.results[i].poster_path;
    newbbcode = bbcode.replace(imglink, "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+ posterpath);

    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "myTr" + i);
    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createTextNode(jsonResponse.results[i].title);
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("myTr" + i).appendChild(z);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createElement("IMG");
    t.setAttribute("src", "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92"+jsonResponse.results[i].poster_path);
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("myTr" + i).appendChild(z);

    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createElement("INPUT");
    t.setAttribute("type","button");
    t.setAttribute("value","pick this");
    t.addEventListener("click", function(){workwithnewbbcode(newbbcode)} );
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("myTr" + i).appendChild(z);

        })(j);
      }
     }
```

Maybe someone has a very simple (noob friendly^^) idea to do that with javascript.
Thank you guys!

**EDIT:**
 Thanks to Jaromanda X for the solution!
instead of

```
newbbcode = bbcode.replace(imglink, "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+ posterpath);
```

just add var

```
var newbbcode = bbcode.replace(imglink, "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400"+ posterpath);
```

**OR**

```
    if (this.status === 200) {

    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    totalresults = jsonResponse.total_results;

    if (totalresults === 0) {
        noresult();
    } else if (totalresults === 1) {
        oneresult();
    } else {

        var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
        table.id = "myTable";
        table.border = "1";

        jsonResponse.results.forEach(function(result) {
            var posterpath = result.poster_path;
            var newbbcode = bbcode.replace(imglink, "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400" + posterpath);

            var tr = document.createElement("TR");

            var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
            td1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result.title));
            tr.appendChild(td1);

            var td2 = document.createElement("TD");
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.src = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w92" + posterpath;
            td2.appendChild(img);
            tr.appendChild(td2);

            var td3 = document.createElement("TD");
            var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
            input.type = "button";
            input.value ="pick this";
            input.addEventListener("click", function() {
                workwithnewbbcode(newbbcode);
            });
            td3.appendChild(input);
            tr.appendChild(td3);

            table.appendChild(tr);
        });
        document.getElementById("log").appendChild(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I already tried an "Immediately-Invoked Function Expression"` - then it should work just fine - of course `newbbcode` SHOULD be declared `var newbbcode` for it to work correctly

Comment: okay...wow...works...was not in my mind to change that.
seems that i dont really understand whats the difference between "var x= 1" and just "x = 1"...thanks alot!

Comment: you can also avoid IIFE altogether by using `jsonResponse.results.forEach(function(result) {`

Comment: also, the way you're building up the table is inefficient - see https://pastebin.com/RiHYg8Ms (edited, first pastebin had issues)

Comment: the way you're adding elements requires repaint after repaint - by doing it the way I suggest, there's a single repaint when the table is added to the DOM

Comment: inside a function `var x = 1` is a locally scoped variable, whereas `x = 1` unless `x` is declared in some outer scope, `x` will be global

Comment: makes sense!!gonna check your link out! 
thank you very much for your work!!

Comment: don't call it "work" ... I'll have to charge you (just kidding)

Comment: fyi @hell this mechanism is called "Hoisting", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

```
for (var i=0;i<10;i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
  },1000);
}
```

You will always get 10 in the output because by the time the nested function is called, the variable i already reached the end of the loop.

In your case, your response object arrives in an XHR callback. This has the same flow as setTimeout. You can create a function wrapper to keep the iterator variable in the call stack:

```
var myfunc=function(x){ //a function that returns a function
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(x);
  },1000);
}

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) myfunc(i);
```